# Is System.nanoTime() still unreliable for long intervals?

Tags: java, time

There has been some prior debate as to the accuracy of Java's System.nanoTime().  The underlying implementation seems to evolve with kernels and kit.  It still seems to not be fully related to the actual time on a machine.  I ran the following code over 5 hours whilst it was sleeping.  I then plotted the results. It's Java 7 /Windows 7.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + "********************");
    long baseMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long baseNanos = System.nanoTime();


    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {                     // 5 hours overall
        Thread.sleep(180_000);


        long deltaMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - baseMillis;
        long deltaNanos = System.nanoTime() - baseNanos;
        long delta = deltaMillis * 1_000_000 - deltaNanos;        // In nS
        System.out.println(delta);
    }


    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + "********************");
}
```

[image: Time drift plot]

The graph shows a surprisingly consistent negative correlation between real time and nano time.  The wobbly red line is the actual data, and the green a trend line (with fitting equation).  Nano time runs slower in my case to the tune of 0.01 ms/s.  This is what I'd expect if nano time is a cpu counter subjected to hard and soft interrupts.

I've only managed to trace my implementation of nano time to `public static native long currentTimeMillis()`.  After that it descends into C & mystery.  I can't understand why if you have an ntp locked real time clock, nano time isn't synced to it.

Can you rely on System.nanoTime() for anything > few seconds yet?

Comment: The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--) states quite clearly that `nanoTime()` "can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time". So comparing it to `currentTimeMillis` is comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: @MickMnemonic OP is comparing differences, not absolute time.

Comment: @Andreas, the semantics of `currentTimeMillis` (which returns the "_current time_ in milliseconds") and `nanoTime` are very different, so the comparison doesn't make much sense.

Comment: nanoTime() and currentTimeMillis() use different clocks. IIRC on Windows, nanoTime() uses [high resolution timers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer), while currentTimeMillis() uses the legacy real-time clock

Comment: [Nanotrusting the nanotime](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/) is also a good read.

Comment: Can you link to any of this "prior debate" you're referring to?

Comment: @dimo414 I'm referring to the contents of the list of nanoTime "Related" questions probably showing down the right hand side of your screen as you read this...

Comment: That is an automatically generated list of questions *possibly* related to this one.  Which "prior debate" did *you* actually read before posting this question?

Comment: @dimo414 I randomly clicked four or six related questions that were suggested by this server when I typed in the title of my question.  Those seemed to be a few years old.  Are you thinking of something specific?

Comment: You say "*There has been some prior debate as to the accuracy of Java's System.nanoTime().*" - I'm asking what prior debate you are referring to.  I too could randomly click on articles, but if I read different articles than you did, we'll wind up talking past each other.  Why can't you just link to whatever you read?

Comment: Put another way, you suggest that in the past people have believed `System.nanoTime()` cannot be relied upon for intervals larger than a few seconds.  Providing context for that claim would help determine if it no longer applies.